# Can you set x == y equal to a Boolean in any any programming languages where x and y are of the same primitive type?

Tags: boolean

This may be an odd question, and generally I would just go test it, but I'm not near a computer with any IDEs, but can you set a Boolean equal to the expression x==y?  The only reason I ask this is because in an if statement you can say... if(x==y) which is asking if the two are equal then do.... And if that is true then the statement x == y is evaluating to true can you set a variable to it

Comment: Languages not strongly typed such as PHP can present issues when comparing int 0 to bool 0 though you can cast and whatnot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, in Java you can do:

```
boolean z = (x==y);
```

Comment: And also in C, C++ and numerous other related languages.

Comment: This lack of a distinction between conditionals and Booleans seems to take a surprisingly long time for many new developers to internalise. Worth noting that the parentheses are unnecessary—`z = x == y` says “`z` is whether `x` equals `y`”. There is nothing special about conditional operators, and Booleans are just values. And in C, `==` actually returns an `int`!